# Adding OData to ASP.NET Core web app and make use of both a ODataBatchHandler and the service configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using OData in an ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) web app

At first, I needed a way to output CSV (for data exporting feature) and found [this great guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/customize-odata-payload-serialization-format-within-asp-net-core-odata/), it worked by doing so in Program.cs, the magic is adding the 3rd parameter `service => service.AddSingleton<ODataMediaTypeResolver>(sp => new CustomizedMediaTypeResolver()))`  for using the service configuration:

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options
        .EnableQueryFeatures()
        .AddRouteComponents(
            "odata/v1",
            Startup.GetEdmModel(),
            service => service.AddSingleton<ODataMediaTypeResolver>(sp => new CustomizedMediaTypeResolver()))
        .Select()
        .Filter()
        .OrderBy()
        .Count()
    );
```

Then I need to activate the batching OData feature as described in many places [for example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/fundamentals/overview?tabs=visual-studio%2Cnet60#batch-requests). It's also making use of an additional parameter in the `AddRouteComponents` function, this time `new DefaultODataBatchHandler()`. For example:

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options
        .EnableQueryFeatures()
        .AddRouteComponents(
            "odata/v1",
            Startup.GetEdmModel(),
            new DefaultODataBatchHandler())
        .Select()
        .Filter()
        .OrderBy()
        .Count()
    );
```

### My question

I would like to call `AddRouteComponents` and make use of both the `DefaultODataBatchHandler` *as well as* the service configuration for registering the `ODataMediaTypeResolver`.

[One is using this method](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/ODataOptions.cs#L127) and [the other that method](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/ODataOptions.cs#L115), but I don't see a way to use a mix of the 2 :(

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source codes

```
public ODataOptions AddRouteComponents(string routePrefix, IEdmModel model, ODataBatchHandler batchHandler)
            {
                return AddRouteComponents(routePrefix, model, services => services.AddSingleton(sp => batchHandler));
            }
```

has indicates:

```
.AddRouteComponents(
            "odata/v1",
            Startup.GetEdmModel(),
            new DefaultODataBatchHandler())
```

is same with ( add DefaultODataBatchHandler()  to IServiceCollection )

```
.AddRouteComponents(
            "odata/v1",
            edmModel,
            services=> {
                services.AddSingleton(sp => new DefaultODataBatchHandler());
               
                })
```

If you want to mix them up,have you tried :

```
.AddRouteComponents(
            "odata/v1",
            edmModel,
            services=> {
                services.AddSingleton(sp => new DefaultODataBatchHandler());
                services.AddSingleton<ODataMediaTypeResolver>(sp => new CsvMediaTypeResolver());
                })
```